# In Visualforce pages, is it possible to use the command line in the Firebug console?

Tags: firebug, salesforce, visualforce

On Visualforce pages, commands run in the Firebug console command line don't seem to work. For example `$(".myClass").show();` returns `TypeError: $(".moreInfo") is null`.

I think this is because the Visualforce is all inside an iframe, so my jQuery is included inside the iframe and all the elements I'm trying to select are also inside this iframe. I'm looking for a workaround if anyone knows of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user viewing the Visualforce page is in development mode, the Visualforce page will be displayed in an IFRAME.

So try disabling "development mode" on your user's User Detail Page.

Søren

Answer (score 1):

I've always found when using jQuery with VisualForce that it's best to use `jQuery.noConflict()` when the page loads and then reference it via `jQuery()` as opposed to `$()` thereafter.

I've just tried using both `$(xx)` and `jQuery(xx)` in the console — the former shows the same error you're seeing, the latter works correctly.

Matt