# closing the current popup window on button click in apex using salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, apex-code

i am in a strange situation

I have an apex page
inside that page there is a button on the click of which i call a a javascript method.
From this method i call window.open(url) and open a new popup window.

Now this new window is also an apex page.
This window contains a button.on the click of this button i want to close the current popup window using javascript.

can anybody suggest me what should i do?

i have tried:

**

```
window.close();
self.close();
```

**

I have tried with **apex command button** as well as with the **HTML button.**

but still window cant be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps same issue as this: [In Visualforce pages, is it possible to use the command line in the Firebug console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357557/in-visualforce-pages-is-it-possible-to-use-the-command-line-in-the-firebug-conso/7372047#7372047)

So try disabling development mode on your user.

Søren

Comment: Søren the idea works gr8.  i have one issue : if i disable the development mode then on button click the window gets closed but before the window.close method i have used remoting method to capture some values from database.this does not works.can u give any suggestion....thank u

Comment: Swati - good to hear. Sounds like you're troubleshooting another problem than what you asked for in the question above. I suggest you post a new question for it with some additional details about how/what it is you're trying to do.